# Unable to understand output of program

Tags: c

I want to know how the output of this program is 3 3=3

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
 main()
{
int a=2,b=3;
printf("%d %d=%d",a,b,a=b);
getch();
}
```

Comment: Because "a=b" is an assignment.

Comment: @user3582228 what output did you expect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The order of evaluation of function arguments is *unspecified* - there's no guarantee that they are evaluated from left-to-right, right-to-left, or any other order, so it's not guaranteed that `a` or `b` are evaluated before `a=b`.

But you've invoked *undefined* behavior because you're trying to both read and modify the value of `a` without an intervening sequence point; since the order of evaluation is unspecified, the result will be different for different platforms, compilers, programs, optimization settings, etc.  *Undefined* behavior simply means that the compiler isn't required to handle this case in any particular way, so *any* result is possible and, as far as the language is concerned, correct.